# Plus sign in MySQL query varchar content, update fails

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute an `UPDATE` query in which `VARCHAR` typed column value includes a plus sign. My query does not update the row and if I remove plus signs from the varchar typed column value it works.

I have tried `mysql_real_escape_string` in PHP and replacing + with \+ in query (executed directly in PHPMyAdmin) but neither of these did work.

Problem is the query which is formatted like

```
UPDATE tableName SET someVariable = 'SomeValueThatContains+Sign' WHERE someId='IdValue';
```

and as I said earlier

```
UPDATE tableName SET someVariable = 'SomeValueThatContains\\+Sign' WHERE someId='IdValue';
```

does not work (when executed in PHPMyAdmin).

Could this be something about character set database is using or something like that? Any suggestions how to edit query to update the row?

Comment: You actually get a error message?

Comment: I just updated my varchar field with a plus sign without any problems.

Comment: There is no reason why this should not work, and in my short test in phpMyAdmin it worked as expected.

Comment: I get no error message, just "0 rows affected". If I do Select with same WHERE-conditions I get one row as result.

Comment: If I remove + signs, I get 1 row affected and it works fine. I have never had this problem before and I'm thinking if it might be some DB properties that causes this since this seems to be really weird problem...

Answer (score -1):

When you use double backslash sign(\\), then it will appear one line.
So You need to insert four time backslash sign(\\\\), then it will appear two time.

## Your Query

```
UPDATE tableName SET someVariable = 'SomeValueThatContains\\\\+Sign' WHERE someId='IdValue';
```

## Example

```
UPDATE employee SET someVariable ='rizwan\\\\+' Where someId=3;
```

Try it. There is no db property issue for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Length of the varchar column is enough for the varchar I'm trying to put in it. I'm almost sure I have had this working in some other project earlier. That's why I'm assuming it has something to do with DB properties/options since I can't understand why this is not working. Still don't know what could cause this...

Comment: Thanks! That works! It is because I have to escape \ first to use another \ to escape +?